# Python code for reading received email

Tags: python

I was writing a code in python for reading the last email, but the message was showing in HTML. How can I get the output in console in text form?

Pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/rUM3i8C0

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

Comment: Could you paste the HTML you get in the email?